# How do I unit test child functions with jest and enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that looks like this:

```
const TestComponent = ({ mobile }) => (
  <>
    <div>
      Your estimate
      {!mobile && (
        <InfoButton>
          {target => (
            <Tooltip
              target={target}
            >
              My tooltip text
            </Tooltip>
          )}
        </InfoButton>
      )}
    </div>
  </>
);
```

I'm trying to add a unit test for this using jest and enzyme and run into an issue when I try to look for `Tooltip` being rendered. I believe this is because it's rendered by a function so when I debug in jest this is what I see

```
  <InfoButton className="infoButton">
    [function]
  </InfoButton>
```

And I can't `.find()`or `.dive()` further into to actually look for the `Tooltip` component. How do I get that function to actually render content when testing with jest?

UPDATE: Adding my test

```
it("should render info button with tooltip", () => {
  const wrapper = renderSubject(); // My render fn which randers the parent compoennt
  const testComponent = wrapper
    .find("TestComponent")
    .first()
    .dive();
  expect(testComponent.find("InfoButton").exists()).toBe(true);
  console.log(testComponent.find("InfoButton").debug());
});
```

Comment: Hi @bos570, could you please provide the complete code of your test?

Comment: @mgarcia Added the simple test I was running.

Comment: Can you add the code for the `renderSubject` function, please?

Comment: It's not very relevant..just renders the parent component that `TestComponent` is being rendered in.

`const renderSubject = (overrideState = {}, overrideProps = {}) => {
  const store = {
    storeVal: {
      ...mockState,
      ...overrideState,
    },
  };

  return shallow(
    <ParentComp store={createStore(() => store)} condensed {...overrideProps} />,
  )
    .dive()
    .dive()
    .dive();
};`

Comment: I don't see where are you rendering the `TestComponent`. As far as I can see from your code you call `renderSubject` without arguments. Can that be the problem?

Comment: @mgarcia the problem is fairly straightforward. Jest doesn't render the component being rendered by the child function of the `InfoButton` component. I wanted to know how that is rendered in just.